# Classic asp boolean to String Language

Tags: vba, casting, type-conversion, boolean

We are doing a migration between servers and now we are passing our classic ASP code.

The fact is that in many places, we have type checks

```
if variablebooleana = "True" then
...
end if
```

The problem is that the server we are migrating has the operating system installed in Spanish and therefore when trying to convert to string instead of returning `"True"` it returns `"Verdadero"`.

Does anyone know how to configure the iis to return `"True"` in these cases?

Thank you very much.

a greeting

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function to do the conversion (`TrueDat()`) and then replace all the occurences of `"True"` with `TrueDat("True")`.  You will have to then fix the `"True"` in the `TrueDat()` and everything should function properly.

[image]

```
Function TrueDat(TheTruth As String) As Boolean
     TrueDat = TheTruth = "True" Or TheTruth = "Verdadero"
End Function
```